# PoshWSUS - how to get last patch date per server?

Tags: poshwsus

so I have this PoshWSUS module and a script which runws on WSUS and makes a CSV file. I am trying to update it so it also contains **last patch date** column but have trouble figuring it out

```
Import-Module -name poshwsus -force
Import-module -name SysDBApi -force
Import-module -name EncryptedCredential -force -ErrorAction Stop

#get credentials
$cred = Import-Clixml 'E:\WCO\transit.xml'
$SysDBcred = Import-Clixml 'E:\WCO\SysDBCred.xml'
$UseSSL = $True
$Port = 8530
$Date = get-date -Format dd-MM-yyyy
$Time = get-date -format HHmmss
$Filename = "$($env:COMPUTERNAME)_$($Date)_$($Time)"


[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration") | out-null

Connect-PSWSUSServer -WsusServer $env:COMPUTERNAME -Port $Port
$ClientInfoHash = Get-PSWSUSClient | 
    Group-Object -Property Id -AsHashTable -AsString 
$UpdateScope = New-PSWSUSUpdateScope -UpdateApprovalActions Install -ExcludedInstallationStates NotApplicable 
$Classifications = Get-PSWSUSClassification | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "Security Updates" }
$UpdateScope.Classifications.AddRange($Classifications)
$WsusData = Get-PSWSUSUpdateSummaryPerClient -UpdateScope $UpdateScope
$WsusData | 
    Select-Object @{name="Computer name";Expression={($ClientInfoHash[$_.ComputerTargetID].FullDomainName).split(".",2) | select -first 1}},
                  @{name="Domain name";Expression={
                      if ( ($ClientInfoHash[$_.ComputerTargetID].FullDomainName).split(".",2)[1])
                      {
                        ($ClientInfoHash[$_.ComputerTargetID].FullDomainName).split(".",2) | select -last 1
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        "WORKGROUP"
                      }
                  }},

                  @{name="Customer";Expression={(Get-SysDBHost -Credentials $SysDBcred -ComputerName ( ($ClientInfoHash[$_.ComputerTargetID].FullDomainName).split(".",2) | select -first 1)).Customer}},
                  @{name="Last reported status";Expression={$ClientInfoHash[$_.ComputerTargetID].LastReportedStatusTime}},
                  @{name="Required Updates";expression={$_.needed}}, 
                  @{name="Total Updates";expression={($_.Installed+$_.Needed+$_.PendingReboot+$_.Failed)}}, 
                  @{name="% Of Compliance";expression={"$([math]::Round((($_.Installed / ($_.Installed+$_.Needed+$_.PendingReboot+$_.Failed)) * 100),0))%"}}, 
                  @{name="Operating System";Expression={$ClientInfoHash[$_.ComputerTargetID].OSDescription}}|
    Export-Csv -Path "E:\Reports\$($Filename)_UpdatesStatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding "utf8" -Delimiter ";"
```

On another WSUS server we use sqlcmd and SQL queries to get this data and the part which gets this info looks like this:

```
SELECT LIP.FullDomainName as 'Server Name',LIP.GroupName as 'Group Name',
LIP.CreationDate as 'Most recent patchinstall date', CASE WHEN NUP.NumUPatches is NULL THEN 0 ELSE NUP.NumUPatches END as 'Number of needed patches' FROM LATESTINSTPATCH LIP LEFT JOIN NumOfUNINSTPATCH NUP ON LIP.ComputerID=NUP.ComputerID
ORDER BY NUP.NumUPatches
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb410149(v=vs.85)
it is in PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdate, but how to work with this in PoshWSUS?

EDIT: I want to also add WSUSgroupname field, but that should be easier...

Answer (score 0):

> **Option** 1 use `Get-PSWSUSUpdate`

The options for the command are [listed here on Github](https://github.com/proxb/PoshWSUS/blob/master/Scripts/Get-PSWSUSUpdate.ps1)

Run `Get-PSWSUSUpdate` with the option then pipe grep the output for date.

---

> **Option 2** native command

is simply  `gwmi win32_quickfixengineering |sort installedon -desc`

---

> **Option 3** PS shell command

```
Get-HotFix |?{$_.InstalledOn -gt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))}
```

Now your script can use something like `@{name="Dates";Expression=...` one of the above options..